# Remove [""] extra characters in Rails 3.2 mapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I'm displaying an estimated budget in **show.html.erb**

I'm using this code:

```
<%= current_user.agency.project_procurement_management_plans.map{|p| p.total_estimated_budget.to_s} %>
```

But then, the output becomes:

```
["117000.5"]
```

How can i detach the output inside `[""]`

Bet it's because of array **(?)** , But how can I prevent it?

Similarly when I'm doing this code in my controller:

```
def create
    @project_procurement_management_plan = ProjectProcurementManagementPlan.new(params[:project_procurement_management_plan])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_procurement_management_plan.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project_procurement_management_plan, notice:"#{@project_procurement_management_plan.code} was successfully created." }
        format.json { render json: @project_procurement_management_plan, status: :created, location: @project_procurement_management_plan }
      else
        #change me soon
        format.html { redirect_to  new_project_procurement_management_plan_path, alert:"#{@project_procurement_management_plan.errors.full_messages}"}
        format.json { render json: @project_procurement_management_plan.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The error messages are located inside the `[""]`

E.g.

```
["Name can't be blank","The password is incorrect"]
```

And so on.

Any workarounds would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-map explains what the `map` method does.  (It always returns an array, as you've noticed, but you should really be understanding what it does.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `map` does return an array with all the elements. If you have only one you shouldn't use `map`:

```
<%= current_user.agency.project_procurement_management_plans.first.total_estimated_budget.to_s %>
```

**EDIT**

For the errors do

```
@project_procurement_management_plan.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
```

This will separate your errors with comma and *and*

Comment: Thank you let me try this one

Comment: By the way, is breakline possible in @project_procurement_management_plan.errors.full_messages.to_sentence? With each errors?

Comment: `array.join("\n")`, but this might not be very useful when shown as HTML. You don't want to put HTML in here, presentation is not the concern of the controller; a helper might work so it becomes something like: `redirect_to ..., alert: error_list(errors)`. My advise is that you keep it simple while you learn.

Comment: Thank you. Ill try to create a helper for this